# Spring MongoDB - Finding Documents between two dates

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am somewhat new to Java and am trying to write a query which will return the documents stored in my mongodb between two dates. I think I am close to getting it correct but am having a hard time getting there. I am receiving the date ranges in the following format:

- [2017-06-29, 2017-07-05]

The dates that i am comparing are stored in the database as follows:

- yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-SSSS

What i have so far..

```
public List<VehicleStatus> getReportingDateRange(List<String> dates)  {

    DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-SSSS");  

    Date startDate = outputFormat.parse(dates.get(0));      
    Date endDate = outputFormat.parse(dates.get(1));

    Query query = new Query();

    Criteria c = new Criteria().andOperator(Criteria.where("updateTime").gte(outputFormat.format(startDate)),  
            Criteria.where("updateTime").lte(outputFormat.format(endDate)));

    query.addCriteria(c);

    return this.mongoOperations.find(query, VehicleStatus.class);

   }
```

I am receiving a parse Exception. I am really not sure where to go from here, any help is greatly appreciated. If you need any additional information please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: Parse `Date startDate = inputFormat.parse(dates.get(0)); Date endDate = inputFormat .parse(dates.get(1));` and your dates should be stored as date type. So no parse to output format is required and `Criteria c = new Criteria().andOperator(Criteria.where("updateTime").gte(startDate),  
            Criteria.where("updateTime").lte(endDate));`

Comment: @Veeram the dates are stored as a String in the DB

Comment: oh okay. try  `String startDate = outputFormat.format(inputFormat.parse(dates[0]));
            String endDate = outputFormat.format(inputFormat.parse(dates[0]));` and pass this to criteria

Comment: @Veeram - that did the trick! Thanks so much for the help. Simple fix but something that i was clearly overlooking. Make an answer and i will make it as correct :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to parse the date into input format followed by formatting the date to output format.

Something like

```
String startDate = outputFormat.format(inputFormat.parse(dates[0])); 
String endDate = outputFormat.format(inputFormat.parse(dates[0]));

Criteria c = new Criteria().andOperator(Criteria.where("updateTime").gte(star‌​tDate), Criteria.where("updateTime").lte(endDate));
```

You should try to save the date as date type and use below version.

```
Date startDate = inputFormat.parse(dates.get(0)); 
Date endDate = inputFormat .parse(dates.get(1));

Criteria c = new Criteria().andOperator(Criteria.where("updateTime").gte(star‌​tDate), Criteria.where("updateTime").lte(endDate));
```